# Door knob strike plate is hitting casing extension/trim

Tags: doors, door-frame, latches, jamb

I installed a one piece security strike plate on my new door frame (it has the openings for both the knob and deadbolt on one plate). I’ve discovered the knob latch hits my jamb extensions (and if the trim was already gouged that as well).  I know the simple solution would be to take the security plate off and just install one with an extended lip, but I still want to maintain the security aspect. Carving out the jamb extension would work, but it would be so deep I think it would look horrible.
Is there some other solution I’m missing? (I can’t find a security strike plate with an extended lip)enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple extended strike plates. Looking at the pictures you posted, this one might be kind of too long, but they come in various lengths, etc. to fit what you need.

[image]

That "security" plate isn't really doing much for overall security. Use extra long screws or drill in some extra screw holes for a bit of added security.

Comment: The security plate allows me to use far more long screws (I used 3”) than what you’re proposing, even if I tried drilling more holes in a longer lip.

Comment: Essentially you're asking _"How do I fix this without actually fixing it?"_ If you drilled three additional screw holes you'd end up with more than the "security" plate.  It's the deadbolt that's going to be most responsible for keeping the door secure, not the strike plate.  The biggest problem is that all those screw holes are in a straight line in the wood grain which weakens the wood and encourages it to split more easily. Hopefully the longer screws will get into the underlying framing and add some strength.